# Select all text in an edit text in a listview on focus

Tags: android, user-interface, android-listview, android-edittext

I have been trying to implement a listview with some edit texts that when focused select all the text. Nothing worked until I found this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24162604/android-edittext-in-listview-with-selection?answertab=active#tab-top. I implemented the code shown and I'm running into a small problem. When the user first opens the activity and taps an edit text it will not select all the text, however if you tap another edit text and then tap the previous one it will select the text just fine. Anyone have any ideas?

Here is some of the code:

```
public class StandSheetCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
private boolean isStartButtonShowing;
private boolean isEndButtonShowing;

private String firstColumnKey;
private String secondColumnKey;
private EditText focusedEditText;

private EditText selectAllFocusedEditText;

private View.OnClickListener mOnClickListener;

private Context mContext = null;
private Map<Integer, ContentValues> contentValuesMap = Maps.newHashMap();

private View.OnClickListener minusListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        EditText editText = (EditText) view.getTag(R.id.edit_text_key);

        updateEditText(editText, false);

    }
};

private View.OnClickListener plusListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        EditText editText = (EditText) view.getTag(R.id.edit_text_key);

        updateEditText(editText, true);
    }
};

private TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        if(s.length()==1){
            selectAllFocusedEditText = null;
        }
    }
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){}
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){}
};

public StandSheetCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor, int flags, int standSheetType){
    super(context, cursor, flags);

    switch (standSheetType){
        case 0:
            firstColumnKey= InventoryContract.StockItem.CursorColumns.ACTUAL_START_COUNT;
            secondColumnKey= InventoryContract.StockItem.CursorColumns.ACTUAL_END_COUNT;
            break;
        case 1:
            firstColumnKey= InventoryContract.StockItem.CursorColumns.TRANSFER_IN_COUNT;
            secondColumnKey= InventoryContract.StockItem.CursorColumns.TRANSFER_OUT_COUNT;
            break;
        case 2:
            firstColumnKey= InventoryContract.StockItem.CursorColumns.GRATIS_COUNT;
            secondColumnKey=InventoryContract.StockItem.CursorColumns.WASTE_COUNT;
            break;
    }

    // Cache context for use in click listeners
    mContext = context;
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.standsheet_type_list_item, parent, false);

    view.findViewById(R.id.column2_item_shim).setOnClickListener(mOnClickListener);
    view.findViewById(R.id.column3_item_shim).setOnClickListener(mOnClickListener);

    return view;
}

public void setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener listener) {
    mOnClickListener = listener;
}

private int getCount(Integer itemIndex, String columnKey){
    int startCountNum=0;
    Cursor c = mContext.getContentResolver().query(InventoryContract.StockItem.getStockItemUri(itemIndex), null, null, null, null);
    if (c != null) {
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            startCountNum = CursorUtil.getLong(c, columnKey).intValue();
        }
        c.close();
    }
    return startCountNum;
}

private View.OnFocusChangeListener focusChangeListener = new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        EditText et = (EditText) v;
        if (!hasFocus) {
            focusedEditText = null;

            updateEditText(et);
        }
        else if(hasFocus) {
            focusedEditText = (EditText)v;
            selectAllFocusedEditText = (EditText)v;
        }
    }
};

@Override
public void bindView(View view, final Context context, final Cursor cursor) {
    Integer index = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(InventoryContract.StockItem.CursorColumns.ID));

    TextView itemName=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.stock_item_name);
    itemName.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(InventoryContract.StockItem.CursorColumns.NAME)));

    EditText firstColumnET=(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.column2_et);
    firstColumnET.setTag(R.id.index_key, index);
    firstColumnET.setTag(R.id.column_key, firstColumnKey);
    firstColumnET.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(firstColumnKey)));
    firstColumnET.setOnFocusChangeListener(focusChangeListener);
    firstColumnET.setFocusable(isStartButtonShowing);
    firstColumnET.setFocusableInTouchMode(isStartButtonShowing);
    firstColumnET.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);


    EditText secondColumnET=(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.column3_et);
    secondColumnET.setTag(R.id.index_key, index);
    secondColumnET.setTag(R.id.column_key, secondColumnKey);
    secondColumnET.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(secondColumnKey)));
    secondColumnET.setOnFocusChangeListener(focusChangeListener);
    secondColumnET.setFocusable(isEndButtonShowing);
    secondColumnET.setFocusableInTouchMode(isEndButtonShowing);
    secondColumnET.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
    secondColumnET.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);

    ImageButton startCountMinButton = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.column2_minus_btn);
    startCountMinButton.setVisibility(isStartButtonShowing ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE);
    startCountMinButton.setTag(R.id.index_key, index);
    startCountMinButton.setTag(R.id.column_key, firstColumnKey);
    startCountMinButton.setTag(R.id.edit_text_key, firstColumnET);
    startCountMinButton.setOnClickListener(minusListener);

    ImageButton startCountPlusButton = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.column2_plus_btn);
    startCountPlusButton.setVisibility(isStartButtonShowing ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE);
    startCountPlusButton.setTag(R.id.index_key, index);
    startCountPlusButton.setTag(R.id.column_key, firstColumnKey);
    startCountPlusButton.setTag(R.id.edit_text_key, firstColumnET);
    startCountPlusButton.setOnClickListener(plusListener);

    ImageButton endCountMinButton = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.column3_minus_btn);
    endCountMinButton.setVisibility(isEndButtonShowing ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE);
    endCountMinButton.setTag(R.id.index_key, index);
    endCountMinButton.setTag(R.id.column_key, secondColumnKey);
    endCountMinButton.setTag(R.id.edit_text_key, secondColumnET);
    endCountMinButton.setOnClickListener(minusListener);

    ImageButton endCountPlusButton = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.column3_plus_btn);
    endCountPlusButton.setVisibility(isEndButtonShowing ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE);
    endCountPlusButton.setTag(R.id.index_key, index);
    endCountPlusButton.setTag(R.id.column_key, secondColumnKey);
    endCountPlusButton.setTag(R.id.edit_text_key, secondColumnET);
    endCountPlusButton.setOnClickListener(plusListener);

    view.findViewById(R.id.column2_item_shim).setVisibility(isStartButtonShowing ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
    view.findViewById(R.id.column3_item_shim).setVisibility(isEndButtonShowing ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);

    if(selectAllFocusedEditText!=null){
        selectAllFocusedEditText.requestFocus();
        selectAllFocusedEditText.selectAll();
    }
}
```

Here is the xml file for each item in the list

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:minHeight="@dimen/list_minimum_height">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/stock_item_name"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/standard_padding"
    android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_medium"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:focusable="false" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center">
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/column2_minus_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/minus_btn_red"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:text="@string/minus_sign" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/column2_et"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minWidth="@dimen/edit_text_minimum_width"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_medium"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/column2_minus_btn"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:digits="0123456789"/>
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/column2_plus_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/plus_btn_green"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/column2_et"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:text="@string/plus_sign" />
    <View
        android:id="@+id/column2_item_shim"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/column2_et"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/column2_et"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/column2_plus_btn"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/column2_minus_btn"
        android:clickable="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center">
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/column3_minus_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/minus_btn_red"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:text="@string/minus_sign" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/column3_et"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minWidth="@dimen/edit_text_minimum_width"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_medium"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/column3_minus_btn"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:digits="0123456789"/>
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/column3_plus_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/plus_btn_green"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/column3_et"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:text="@string/plus_sign" />
    <View
        android:id="@+id/column3_item_shim"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/column3_et"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/column3_et"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/column3_plus_btn"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/column3_minus_btn"
        android:clickable="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is delayed, but I had this problem for weeks and I want to post the solution that worked for me in case any other users stumble across this post (as it is the precise problem I had).

Go into your Android Manifest and in the Activity you are specifying, add:

> android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"

As you mentioned, you are not having an issue with your EditText gaining focus OR your EditText selecting all data when clicked - BOTH of those are happening. So your issue is not implementation of requestFocus() or setSelectAllOnFocus().

When you click on your EditText, your ListView will re-call getView because the soft keyboard has redefined the Activity's main window to make room for the keyboard.

By calling "adjustPan", you are electing NOT to resize the Activity's main window (which calls getView a second time), but rather ensure simply that whatever has focus on the screen continues to stay on the screen. Whatever is in focus will pan, if necessary, to stay on the screen.

Add this and hopefully you will be good to go! Again, this solution is for those who have the issue of your EditText selecting all properly BUT only on the second time it is clicked.

Comment: This didn't work for me, because after onFocusChange is called, the list view (or framework?) would adjust/clear the text selection. Had to move the selectAll() into a handler to make sure it would be called after framework adjustments.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but might help others as I faced the exact opposite issue: selectAll() during first OnFocusChanged call worked, but any selectAll() during subsequent OnFocusChanged call would not.

I simply moved the selectAll() into a runnable handler as follows and it then worked as expected!

```
@Override
public void onFocusChange(final View edit_text_widget, boolean hasFocus)
{
    if (hasFocus)
    {
        new Handler().post(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                edit_text_widget.selectAll();
            }
        });
    }
}
```